# password reset related problem

Tags: ssis

how to reset password in every 3months in ssis package dynamically updated?how

Comment: Can you maybe reword your question so that it makes sense? Everything that comes after "how to reset password" is just a random stream of words.

Comment: Can you let us know the security context you are using for your package?  Eg Windows authentication, named user/login etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could store passwords in a XML configuration file.  That would mean you would have to replace the XML configuration file through some script.
2. You could store the password in a database table.  Not a good way to do it since anyone with access to the database could query it, but that could work.
3. You could eliminate the need for a password and use NT authentication if the service account doesn't change passwords, but that may not be possible in your situation.
4. You could store the passwords in an unencrypted manner locally and write a script to find and replace the password in the DTSX files and then script deploying the files.  Again, storing the passwords in clear text may not be a good idea even though this approach is technically feasible.
5. You could override connection passwords in the SQL Server Agent job.  One advantage of this approach is that you could easily script out the jobs and run a mass find/replace on the scripts.